# Is there a way to create multiple DELETE triggers on the same table?

Tags: python, triggers, sqlite

Say i have a table of students, their classes, and their total grade-point-average:

```
CREATE TABLE [records](
    student TEXT NOT NULL,
    class TEXT DEFAULT '',             
    gpa REAL DEFAULT 0.0);
```

In this table, the student can either drop a class...

```
DELETE FROM records WHERE student=? AND class=?
```

...or drop out of school:

```
DELETE FROM records WHERE student=?
```

Each event should activate a different trigger. How would one write these triggers in SQLite? Because...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [drop_a_class] AFTER DELETE ON records
    WHEN (DELETE FROM records WHERE student=old.student AND class=old.class)
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

...doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. Why not to put your functionality to single one?

Comment: @IgorPopov: I've changed the `grades` column to answer this. If the student drops a class, a trigger could be altering the student's GPA. If a student drops out, a trigger could be appending his information in a `school_dropout` table. Can you think of a work-around for my example?

Comment: Having worked in educational technologies I would highly suggest that flat out deleting records is NOT the way you want to handle these situations if your app has any probability of being used in a production environment.

Comment: @ChrisLively: :-) This is just a silly example--the simplest way i could think to explain a more complex issue; though i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says:

> SQLite supports only FOR EACH ROW triggers, not FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers.

And the information you have in the WHEN clause is only the contents of the record to be deleted.

You cannot differentiate these cases from within a trigger.
You have to implement this in your application.